# Cannot install perl module Email::Sender on Centos 6.7

Tags: perl, module, centos, cpan

I am trying to install this perl module, Email::Sender;
I have tried running this command first as root:

```
perl -MCPAN -e 'install("Email::Sender")'
```

It failed to make the test and make install test, below the output:

```
Warning (usually harmless): 'YAML' not installed, will not store     persistent state
Running make test
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/usr/bin/perl" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM"             "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/00-load.t ............ 1/? 
#   Failed test 'use Email::Sender::Simple;'
#   at t/00-load.t line 3.
#     Tried to use 'Email::Sender::Simple'.
#     Error:  Can't locate List/MoreUtils.pm in @INC (@INC contains:     /root/.cpan/build/Email-Sender-1.300021-JAe4AH/blib/lib /root/.cpan/build    /Email-Sender-1.300021-JAe4AH/blib/arch /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local    /share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl     /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at /root/.cpan/build/Email-Sender-    1.300021-JAe4AH/blib/lib/Email/Sender/Util.pm line 10.
# BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /root/.cpan/build/Email-Sender-1.300021-JAe4AH/blib/lib/Email/Sender/Util.pm line 10.
# Compilation failed in require at /root/.cpan/build/Email-Sender-1.300021-JAe4AH/blib/lib/Email/Sender/Simple.pm line 24.
# BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /root/.cpan/build/Email-Sender-1.300021-JAe4AH/blib/lib/Email/Sender/Simple.pm line 24.
# Compilation failed in require at t/00-load.t line 3.
# BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/00-load.t line 3.
Bailout called.  Further testing stopped:  can't even compile all     relevant modules
FAILED--Further testing stopped: can't even compile all relevant modules
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
  RJBS/Email-Sender-1.300021.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports RJBS/Email-Sender-1.300021.tar.gz
Warning (usually harmless): 'YAML' not installed, will not store     persistent state
Running make install
make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
```

I have even tried to run it from the CPAN shell, but no luck.

Any for some suggestions?

Comment: Hi, this is centos 6.7; In fact I have figured it out and some dev gcc were missing

Comment: yum install gcc gcc-c++ make openssl-devel  solved it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
yum install gcc gcc-c++ make openssl-devel
```

Solved the Perl install module.